# Dúvida sobre template-parts no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Eu já vi que em vários temas wordpress tem a pasta **template-parts** e que nessa pasta comtém arquivos por ex: content.php e etc... e que esse arquivos são carregados em outras partes do tema com a função get-templates-parts(...);

A minha dúvida é, se eu criar um arquivo exemplo parede.php dentro da pasta template-parts contendo poucas linhas de código e depois eu chamo esse parede.php dentro do header.php ele funcionária normalmente ou não? existe alguma regra para uso dessa pasta? eu posso criar meus arquivos personalizados.php para reduzir outros códigos que ficaram grandes demais ou não?

Comment: ou alguém pode ao menos me explicar  pra quer serve essa pasta?